# Dark mode in chrome-based browsers

Tags: chromium, flag, dark-mode

I'd like to run chrome-based browser with a dark-mode on.

I can do it by

1. going to:    chrome://flags
2. finding #enable-force-dark flag
3. setting it "Enabled"

It works on my Linux system both on Chromium and Vivaldi, but it's a cumbersome approach when you need to toggle between dark/light mode everyday.

So is there any easier/faster way of setting specific flag? The best option would be to create a shortcut button for this action, but is it possible and how to do it?

As a substitute I wanted to run a browser from a command line with a specific flag set to "enabled" but it doesn't work.
I found [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that there is a "force-dark-mode" flag and according to [this page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags),
I tried to run

```
chromium --force-dark-mode
```

and

```
chromium --force-dark-mode=enabled
```

In chromium it has no effect on the content of the page, it just changes the colour of the window frame. In vivaldi it has no effect at all. I also tried

```
chromium --enable-force-dark
```

Again, it has no effect at all neither in Chromium nor in Vivaldi.
What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Finally, I found the answer that works for me. [Here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/x5xrFgYiDuE) it is said that the correct command that allows running browser with dark mode on is:

```
chromium --enable-features=WebContentsForceDark
```

I still don't know how to toggle it with the use of a button.

EDIT:
I've just found that source code for [dark reader extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=pl) is published on [github](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader). I compiled the source code locally and got it working. This clears up all my doubts and fears concerning the privacy and security of the chromium extensions.

Comment: Btw: for me, it does NOT change the Chromium UI to darkmode, but successfully sets the darkmode css definitions

Answer (score 0):

to use a dark theme for the chromium UI, set the environment variables `GTK_THEME` and `XDG_DATA_DIRS`

on the opposite, to force light mode for the chromium UI, unset the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` env

note: this is different (better) than "pick a theme color" in `chrome://settings/manageProfile` because with this, everything is dark, where chromium's "theme color" allows me to pick only one color, and there are still white areas in the UI

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# chromium-darkmode.sh

#export GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark
export GTK_THEME=Breeze-Dark

# note: XDG_DATA_DIRS can be multiple paths separated by ":"
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share # debian/arch/...
#export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/run/current-system/sw/share # nixos

gtkrc_path="$XDG_DATA_DIRS/themes/$GTK_THEME/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"

if ! [ -e "$gtkrc_path" ]; then
  echo "error: missing gtkrc file: $gtkrc_path" >&2
  exit 1
fi

echo "ok: using gtkrc file: $gtkrc_path" >&2

exec chromium "$@"
```

example gtkrc file: [Breeze-Dark/gtk-2.0/gtkrc](https://github.com/eXtern-OS/eXternOS-Base/blob/master/squashfs-root/usr/share/themes/Breeze-Dark/gtk-2.0/gtkrc) ([source: breeze-gtk](https://github.com/KDE/breeze-gtk))

alternative: set qt theme via `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` and/or `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE`, and probably also `XDG_DATA_DIRS`, see also [arch wiki: Qt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Qt)